# Mockito test failed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

My test failed, but the real code works well.
I have two simple class:

```
public class BarTest {
    private Bar bar;
    private Food food;

    @Test
    public void checkSizeFood (){
        bar = mock(Bar.class);
        food = mock(Food.class);
        bar.addFood(food);
        assertThat(bar.getsizeBar(),is(1)); //here failed
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question

Answer (score 2):

`bar` is a mock. Calling `addFood` won't actually do anything to the object's state, as its not a "real" `Bar` instance. If you want to test `Bar`'s functionality, you should use a real object, not a mock:

```
bar = new Bar();
food = mock(Food.class);
bar.addFood(food);
assertThat(bar.getsizeBar(), is(1));
```

Comment: Don't understand idea mock object ( When I need it?

Comment: @Mariia usually we use mocks when we want to test some class which has dependencies, so you can mock that dependency and test class itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do **not** understand how to use mocking for unit tests.

The point is: you **only** mock things that your *class under test* needs to do its jobs. To be precise: when your *class under test* calls something that you have to control, then you create a mocked instance of that class and use that to construct that *object under test* on which you later invoke a method.

Therefore it doesn't make sense that a class call `BarTest` **mocks** an instance of Bar.

And in your case, the test case should (most likely!) read:

```
Bar underTest = new Bar();
bar.add(new Foo());
assertThat(bar.getSize(), is(1));
```

Please note:

- you only mock objects if you absolutely have to - so when you can create a Foo object using `new` in your unit test - then do so. Of course, if `add()` call methods on that Foo object things would be different. But then this method shouldn't be called `add()` in the first place.
- naming continued: that method should be named `getSize()` - not `getsizeBar()`: there is no point in putting the class name into the method name, and method names go camelCase, not camelcaseWhatever.

Long story short: it looks like you want to learn mocking/unit testing by trial and error. That is an ineffective approach - you have to understand the **concepts** before putting them in code. Thus: start reading a good book or tutorial (like this [one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html)) first.